# Проблема с плагином jQuery Form Styler

Tags: javascript, html, css

Использую плагин jQuery Form Styler для стилизации элементов формы,
есть select с несколькими пунктами. Не могу сделать так, чтобы выбранный пункт не отображался в выпадающем списке. http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/

Answer (score 1):

```
.jq-selectbox .sel{display: none !important;}
```